# c threads - why does mmsystem (using mciSendString) not play the sound file?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winmm, mcisendstring

I want my game to play some sfx. At the beginning, I open some mp3 file `mciSendString("open Muzle.mp3 alias Muzle");`.

My problem is that `mciSendString("play Muzle from 0");` still causes a little lag and the game has to play the sounds frequently.

In another question, I read that using threads will solve the problem. I'm completely new to using threads. The problem now is that the sound doesn't play :p . I verified that the thread runs properly by giving a cout at the end.

I have this function now:

```
void Shout(string SoundName){
    string FNstr;
    wstring FNwstr;
    FNstr = "play " + SoundName + " from 0";
    FNwstr.assign(FNstr.begin(), FNstr.end());
    mciSendString(FNwstr.c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL);
    Sleep(2000);
    cout << "Test woi\n";
}
```

(I tried without Sleep too. I wonder if I need it, because if the thread reaches the end, it might get deleted and the sound terminated... I'm not sure how threads or the mmsystem work)

If I simply call this `Shout()` function, it will play the sound, do the Sleep(2000), and then cout. Everything worked fine. But I have to use threads, so I try:

```
thread(Shout, "Muzle");
```

and I got error: abort() has been called. I figured out I may need to detach the thread:

```
thread t(Shout, "Muzle");
t.detach();
```

With this, everything looked to work fine (after 2 seconds, I see the "Test woi" printed on the console), but no sound was played.

Hmm, so thanks for reading everything ^.^ . Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have ONE permanent thread that:
 1. Waits for the sound to finish before moving on (assuming that is the way you want it to work). You can probably just use the ["wait"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) option to do that. 
 2. When not playing a sound, waits for a command to play the next sound - using a [pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send messages to the thread would be one such solution, but you could use other methods.

Comment: I need the game to be able to play multiple sounds at once, so if I understand correctly, I won't use the wait if I only have one thread. But the problem is, the sound doesn't play at all when I call it with a thread xD . I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Ok, I don't know exactly what you need to do. There are lots of things that come up if you google for "play multiple sounds with MCI", and others that come up with "MCIsendstring multiple threads", and some of the suggestions there seem to imply that it's not that easy to do this in a secondary thread - I think because of the way that eventhandling works. If you feel that my answer isn't of any use, I'll delete it.